# How can I detect endpoint annotations in tomcat servlet filter?

Tags: java, tomcat

The goal: Require an authenticated user for all endpoints except for the endpoints that have been specifically annotated as being accessible without any authentication.

In other words, I would like to do something like this

```
@NotSecure
@Path("/notSecure")
public void notSecure()
{
   doUnsecureThings();
}

@Path("/secure")
{
   doSecureThings();
}
```

Where all of the authentication stuff happens tucked away in a servlet filter (or something else, I'm not picky).

How should I approach this?

We are currently using Tomcat 6 (with plans to go to 7 later this year) and java 6 (again, with plans to go to 7 later this year), if that changes anything.

Comment: I'm using netbeans, why?

Comment: That can certainly be done. However, could you maybe share _why_ you'd want to to re-invent the wheel here? Why isn't path-based authentication configured in `web.xml` (or some other security framework) good enough?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know that such security frameworks existed (though, it makes sense, I didn't think what I was trying to do would be that far out there).  I'll look into what I google (shiro is looking interesting).

As for the web.xml stuff. It wouldn't be a good fit with our current code base.  Unfortunately we have put pretty much everything off of the root path.  Some restructuring could help there, but it is a lot of work.